# How can I use a JSON processor rather than jackson or gson in my spring boot application?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to use a JSON processor like [Genson](https://github.com/owlike/genson) in my spring boot application.

When you use `Jackson` or `Gson` you are so comfortable due to the spring boot auto-configuration for these two libraries.

In this [link](https://www.callicoder.com/configuring-spring-boot-to-use-gson-instead-of-jackson/), there is a great guide for replacing `Jackson` with `Gson`.

For solving my problem, I created the `genson` and `gensonBuilder` bean But what should I do to be able to add this line to my config? `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=genson`

Do I need to do anything other than the above for replacing `Jackson` with `Genson` library?

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide for Spring Boot:

**1. First of all exclude JACKSON from your Spring Boot application**

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- Exclude the default Jackson dependency -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

**2. Register converter and Genson class**

Genson has HTTP converter for Spring [com.owlike.genson.ext.spring.GensonMessageConverter](http://genson.io/Documentation/Javadoc/index.html?com/owlike/genson/ext/spring/class-use/GensonMessageConverter.html), [Sources](https://github.com/owlike/genson/blob/master/genson/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/ext/spring/GensonMessageConverter.java).
In case Spring Boot application just create new bean with this converter. It will be applied automatically.

See [Registering a custom MessageConverter in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029021/registering-a-custom-messageconverter-in-spring-boot)

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters)

> Any HttpMessageConverter bean that is present in the context will be
> added to the list of converters

```java
    @Bean
    public Genson genson() {
        return new GensonBuilder().setHtmlSafe(true).setSkipNull(true).useBeanViews(true).create();
    }

    @Bean
    public com.owlike.genson.ext.spring.GensonMessageConverter gensonMessageConverter() {
        return new com.owlike.genson.ext.spring.GensonMessageConverter(genson());
    }
```

`spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=genson` is not required, just remove this config.

Answer (score 0):

To use custom, not supported by default by `Spring` conversion library you need to implement your own `AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter`:

```java
import com.owlike.genson.Genson;
import com.owlike.genson.GensonBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class GensonHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter {

    private Genson genson;

    public GensonHttpMessageConverter() {
        this(new GensonBuilder()
                .useIndentation(true)
                .create());
    }

    public GensonHttpMessageConverter(Genson genson) {
        Assert.notNull(genson, "A Genson instance is required");
        this.genson = genson;
    }

    public void setGenson(Genson genson) {
        Assert.notNull(genson, "A Genson instance is required");
        this.genson = genson;
    }

    public Genson getGenson() {
        return this.genson;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal(Type resolvedType, Reader reader) {
        return getGenson().deserializeInto(reader, resolvedType);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, @Nullable Type type, Writer writer) {
        getGenson().serialize(object, writer);
    }
}
```

After that you need to register it:

```java
import com.example.genson.GensonHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.util.List;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new GensonHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Http Message Converters with the Spring Framework](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest)

Comment: You do not need to create custom converter, Genson has converter for Spring.

Answer (score 0):

For [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi):

```kotlin
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import okio.buffer
import okio.sink
import okio.source
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter
import java.io.*
import java.lang.reflect.Type

class MoshiHttpMessageConverter(private val jsonParser: Moshi) : AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter() {

    init {
        this.supportedMediaTypes = listOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun readInternal(resolvedType: Type, reader: Reader): Any {

        try {
            asInputStream(reader).source().buffer().use { source ->
                val adapter = jsonParser.adapter<Any>(resolvedType)
                return adapter.fromJson(source)!!
            }
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            logger.error("Failed to parse json")
            throw ex
        }
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun writeInternal(value: Any, type: Type?, writer: Writer) {

        try {
            val adapter = jsonParser.adapter<Any>(type ?: error("Type is null"))
            asOutputStream(writer).sink().buffer().use { bufferedSink ->
                adapter.toJson(bufferedSink, value)
                bufferedSink.flush()
            }
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            logger.error("Failed to create json")
            throw ex
        }
    }

    private fun asInputStream(reader: Reader): InputStream {
        return object : InputStream() {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun read(): Int {
                return reader.read()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun asOutputStream(writer: Writer): OutputStream {
        return object : OutputStream() {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun write(b: Int) {
                writer.write(b)
            }
        }
    }
}
```